# Getting Error while converting from JSON String Java Model Class

Tags: java, json, postgresql

I am have a problem in converting JSON String to Java object. As per my scenario Database (PostgreSQL) is returning JSON String in PGOBJECT through function.

Which I am trying to convert into model Class. Returned value JSON sample is:

```
{
  "A_REASON": [
    {
      "cd": "CLOSE",
      "name": "CLOSE",
      "value": "A_REASON",
      "type": "A_REASON"
    }
  ],
  "P_MODE": [
    {
     "cd": "CLOSE",
      "name": "CLOSE",
      "value": "A_REASON",
      "type": "A_REASON"
    }
  ],
  "F_TYPE": [
    {
     "cd": "CLOSE",
      "name": "CLOSE",
      "value": "A_REASON",
      "type": "A_REASON"
    } ] }
```

I have created My Model Classes like below.

```
public class MODEL {

    private List<MISCDTO> A_REASON;

    private List<MISCDTO> P_MODE;

    private List<MISCDTO> F_TYPE; 
  //settter and Getter 
    }

    public class MISCDTO{
     private String  cd;
     private String name;
     private String value;
     private String type;
    }
```

When I am trying to convert into Model Class from JSON String it gives error, I have tried multiple ways

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();    
 MODEL object = mapper.readValue(pGobject.getValue(), MODEL.class);
 List<MODEL> list = mapper.readValue(pGobject.getValue(), new TypeReference<List<MODEL >>(){});
 MODEL object= mapper.readValue(pGobject.getValue(), new TypeReference<MODEL>() {});
```

I am looking to convert into either Map> or MODEL object having List, List etc. Please help. Please do help in Formatting as i am trying to Write in Stack Standard. Still novice on this.

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: Postgres typically returns JSON values as `String`s how exactly are you retrieving that value from the database?

Comment: Check this link - https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/10/entity-object-conversion-to-dto-object.html

Comment: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "A_REASON" (Class com.domain.dto.MODEL), not marked as ignorable

Comment: yes Postgres is returning JSON String. With Output parameter. PGobject pGobject = (PGobject) call.getObject(3);